# How to load JSON data asynchronously and populate UITableView during the data loading in objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

I am beginner in iOS and objective C programming, and I have an issue I didn't manage to solve because I just don't know where to begin, and what to do. Here is the context : I have a sidebar menu (like facebook's one), and when you select a  category of this sidebar menu, I display an UITableView that contents a list of image and some text, the list of image and the text comes from internet with a JSON feed. My app currently works fine, but each time I change the category it freezes the time to load JSON data from internet. Here is a sample of code of my TableViewController.m :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self refreshTable];
}

-(void)refreshTable {
    // Send a synchronous request
    NSURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLValue]];
    NSURLResponse * response = nil;
    NSError * error = nil;
    NSData * data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                      returningResponse:&response
                                                  error:&error];

    if (error == nil)
    {
        // Parse JSON data
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate some explanations with the steps to follow since I am really beginner. I have found some similar questions and they talk about delegate, what is delegate and how do I call it?

Thank you very much guys for taking the time to read my issue.

Comment: Do an async data transfer and parse the JSON in the "transfer completed" method/block.  Then signal the table view to `reloadData` from the JSON.

Comment: I have a project that does this. You can check it out here: https://github.com/AdamPro13/Reddit-Search-and-Share

Comment: In regards to my previous post, you will need to use CocoaPods. They're very straightforward. Once you install them, just run `pod install` in terminal to install the required pods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    // parsing code goes here

    // update table view
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Move your parsing code inside the completion block. For more info see: https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:.

At the end of parsing you can call `[self.tableView reloadData]` to refresh.

Comment: Alternatively you can use `AFNetworking` (https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking), an open source networking library for iOS that has good documentation and makes networking on iOS fun :)

Comment: @Cornelius Very true but since this is simple/he already has `NSURLConnection` I think that the other approach is easier. For more complex tasks though definitely go the `AFNetworking` route.

Comment: We should add that while parsing the response data can be executed on a secondary thread, setting the table view's data (or data source or "model") and invoking `reloadData` should happen on the main thread. ;)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper I have updated the answer to better reflect that point.

Comment: Hi cabellicar123, thank you very much for your answer, it solved my issue, now my app is no more freezing. However the behavior is still not very user-friendly, because the table displays empty for a few seconds and then it is reloaded with data. Can  you tell me how can I add an activity indicator to tell the user that it is refreshing. And also, instead of displaying all the data in one block, I would like to display data as soon as a content of a viewcell is loaded

Comment: @user3414662 No problem. As for your question, you can either add a `UIRefreshControl` to your table view or a `UIActivityIndicatorView` to your main view and start the refresh before the `[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest...]` line and end it after you refresh the table view data. There are a lot of tutorials out there. If you want it to show up for the first time I would recommend the Activity Indicator.

Comment: @user3414662 Yep that would be the way to go. Then all you need to do is right before the asynchronous call put these lines `self.activityIndicatorView.hidden = NO` and `[self.activityIndicatorView startAnimating]`. Then after reloading the data you can write: `[self.activityIndicatorView stopAnimating]` and then `self.activityIndicatorView.hidden = YES`. This assumes that the indicator is initially hidden.

Comment: OK thank you cabellicar123, I managed to add activity indicator. And can you tell me how to instead of displaying all the data in one block, I would like to display data as soon as a content of a viewcell is available

Comment: @user3414662 Well there are probably some more complicated solutions, but a quick hack would be to move the `reloadData` line and call each time you have parsed the data for a cell.

Comment: @cabellicar123 it doesn't work for me because what is time consuming is data loading from internet, not data parsing.. Even if I use     reloadData  each time I have parsed the data for a cell, the cells don't appear one after the other during the data loading. I thought about parsing the data in     (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection  will it solve my issue?

Comment: @user3414662 Yes that creates a much more complicated question. You could split the data up on the server. I'm just not sure if there is a way to guarantee that you have downloaded a certain part of the data. (keep in mind that I don't really know what the data you are parsing looks like).